# PHP code defaulting to an error when it shouldn't be

Tags: php, maxmind

I had a PHP developer create a redirection script that redirects users in specific states to another URL, while letting everyone else visit the website.

The problem is it's redirecting everyone who doesn't match a state listed to the error URL, when it should be letting them visit the site.

I think there's a return missing? What do you guys think?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

require_once '/vendor/autoload.php';

use MaxMind\Db\Reader;

$databaseFile = '/geoip/GeoIP2-City.mmdb';
$ipWhiteList = ['123', '321'];

if(!in_array($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $ipWhiteList)) {
    $reader = new Reader($databaseFile);
    $iso_code = $reader->get($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])['subdivisions'][0]['iso_code'];
    if (!isset($_REQUEST['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        switch($iso_code) {
            case NJ:
                $url = 'http://example.com';
                break;
            case DE:
                $url = 'http://example.com';
                break;
            default:
                $url = 'http://www.example.com/?=error';
                break;
        }
        $reader->close();
        header('Location: '.$url);
        die();
    } else {
        if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "example2.com") > -1) {
            echo "You were redirected from ".urldecode($_REQUEST['referer']).", but it is not available in your area (".$iso_code.").";
            break;
        } else {
            echo "Welcome!";
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: well, what do you expect? You check for NJ/DE. If neither of those matches, you redirect everything else to the error page. e.g. take out the `default` clause.

Comment: The default page is for a query error. For example, their IP address doesn't have an ISO code. If we redirected everyone to the default URL, and that's the URL the script resides on, it would just be a redirect loop.

Comment: then you should return some OTHER value to signify an error and check for that explicitly. e.g. `case 'ZZ': ... invalid`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try loading all the valid values, and checking to make sure it's valid, even if it's not NJ/DE.

```
if (in_array($state, array('NJ', 'DE'))) {
    // Redirect
} elseif (!in_array($states, $all_states_array)) {
    // Go to error.
}
```

The else is implied, in that the script will just continue working. You could structure this several different ways, depending on how much you need to extend it:

```
if (!in_array($state, $all_states_array)) {
    // Error
}

if (in_array($state, array('NJ', 'DE'))) {
   // Redirect
}
```

You could also add all the cases:

```
case 'DE':
    // Do something;
    break;
case 'NJ':
    // Do soemthing;
    break;
case 'PA':
case 'AL':
case 'NY':
case 'OK':
case 'TX':
...
    // Valid, but not the right target.
    break;
default:
    // show error
```

Comment: The problem is there's thousands of ISO Codes (us and abroad) so it wouldn't be realistic. We only want to block 2 states in the US, and everyone else can stay on the page :(

Comment: You should filter by country first. If not in US, just ignore the rest of the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If the state is not from NJ or DE, then do nothing.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

require_once '/vendor/autoload.php';

use MaxMind\Db\Reader;

$databaseFile = '/geoip/GeoIP2-City.mmdb';
$ipWhiteList = ['123', '321'];

if(!in_array($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $ipWhiteList)) {
    $reader = new Reader($databaseFile);
    $iso_code = $reader->get($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])['subdivisions'][0]['iso_code'];
    if (!isset($_REQUEST['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        switch($iso_code) {
            case NJ:
                $url = 'http://example.com';
                header('Location: '.$url);
                                die();
                break;
            case DE:
                $url = 'http://example.com';
                header('Location: '.$url);
                die();
                break;
            default:
        }
        $reader->close();
    } else {
        if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "example2.com") > -1) {
            echo "You were redirected from ".urldecode($_REQUEST['referer']).", but it is not available in your area (".$iso_code.").";
            break;
        } else {
            echo "Welcome!";
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```